# Number of solutions of some trigonometric equations

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Let $N > 1$ and let $S$ be a subset of the *integers* in the (real) interval $[1, N]$. Can we prove that there are only finitely many solutions $x \in [1,N] \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ to the equation
$$
\sum_{s \in S} \dfrac{\sin^2((x-s)\pi)}{x - s} = 0?
$$